# Changing UICollectionView layout depending on section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am currently implementing a `UICollectionView` with several sections (let's say 4) like in the image below:

[image: uicollectionview]

From section 0 to section 2 it is just a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with different cell sizes for each section but for section 3, it is a custom layout (Waterfall layout).

I already have implemented the 2 different layouts and they work well in separate `UICollectionView`, but I have some trouble to switch between the 2 layouts in the same `UICollectionView`.

First of all is it possible to change the layout from a section to another and if it is by which way this can be accomplished.

Comment: did you try `collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout`?

Comment: yes I did try it but maybe not in a good way. But `collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout` will change the layout of the entire UICollectionView right? no only of my specific section (the last one in my exemple)

Comment: Good Idea to use separate collection view. with custom layout it might be complex

Comment: Yes I had this idea too that can reduce the complexity of it. I will try to handle one `UICollectionView` below the other to see how it behave.

Comment: @Florian_L You can use pod `WaterfallLayout` to switch back and forth between flow/waterfall layout for each section.

Comment: https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/WaterfallLayout

Comment: @GovindKumawat looks nice. I'll try to catch the logic first but it seems to be a really good start thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome! let me known if it will work for you.

Comment: @GovindKumawat I finally created my own custom layout based on the Waterfall one, was a great way to learn how `UICollectionViewLayout` works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your question header is a bit misleading. You don't need to change the layout for each section. You need to show different layouts depending on section.

To achieve what you want you must subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` and then determine the layout depending on section. In your case I suggest you to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as it takes a lot of heavy lifting.

`Section 0 - Section 2` of your sample are easily achievable by using just [`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout).

As you have **"full width"** cells there, than you can determine each cell size and insets using the following methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets

func collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) -> CGSize

func collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt: Int) -> CGFloat
```

First problem will appear when you will try to build **Section 3**. For that case I suggest you to search for "Waterfall layout", there are implementations on GitHub. When you will figure out how it works, you should do the following:

1. Create `UICollectionView`
2. Create `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass
3. Set your layout subclass as a collection view layout.
4. For Sections 0-2 use plain `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` possibilities.
5. For Sections like section 4 you should override `func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?` and calculate attributes manually.

Sorry, if my answer is too broad.

Here are some useful links:

- [CollectionView programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH3-SW1)
- [Waterfall layout](https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/WaterfallLayout)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, I'll take a look at this and give it a try.

Comment: it took some time but I finally was able to create my own `UICollectionViewLayout` based on what you gave thank you.